# Как работать с ethernet портом на c++

Tags: c++, port, ethernet

Здравствуйте. У меня есть пульт который подключается к специальному контроллеру через ethernet кабель. Пульт состоит из двух кнопок, а в кабеле имеется только 3 провода. Я хочу подключить компьютеру к контроллеру, что бы компьютер выполнял функции пульта.

План был такой:
Сперва я хотел подключить пульт к компьютеру и узнать какого рода команды он подаёт контроллеру нажимая на кнопки. Далее написать не большой код на основе полученной информации, который давал бы команды на контроллер. Потом уже добавил бы те функции программе которые не мог выполнять пульт.

Проблема в том, что у меня и так не большой опыт в программировании на c++, а о работе с портами я вообще не чего не знаю.

Вопрос: Что потребуется для написания программы которая будет отображать сигнал поступающий на ethernet порт компьютера? Как отправлять сигнал на ethernet порт с помощью c++? Возможно ли вообще всё это?

Ниже приведена "схема" подключений. 1011 символизирует информацию. (1. Нынешнее подключение. 2. Получение сигнала от пульта на компьютер. 3. Отправка сигнала с компьютера на контроллер)[image: Иллюстрация трёх подключений]

Также фотография пульта с обратной стороны.[image: Вид на пульт с низу]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может через адаптор с ethernet на usb

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас не ethernet [витая пара](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0), а визуально похожий [RJ45](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_Jack) разъем, подключаемый к com-порту, а не к сетевой карте

Comment: У ethernet-кабеля жил строго восемь. Здесь их три, значит это точно COM.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что я понятия не имею какой это кабель. Я вижу похожи на ethernet, пишу что это он. Главное, что я не понимаю как с ним работать. Возможно, я взялся за слишком сложный проект для своего уровня, но всё равно хотелось бы узнать что с ним делать. Опираясь на ваши комментарии, думаю что это COM кабель с разъёмом RJ-45. Думаю тогда сделать переходник с RJ-45 на COM разъём с одной стороны.

Comment: @Arhad про строго 8 жил вы неправы, могут использоваться только 4 жилы.

Comment: А в пульте вообще есть контроллер? Судя по фотографии, похоже, что это простая аналоговая схема, где кнопки замыкают контакты. На одном проводе постоянное напряжение, а при нажатии кнопок оно передаётся на другие провода.

Comment: @maestro Так и есть. Пульт подключен к контроллеру через этот кабель, но он не в самом пульте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже выяснили в комментариях, это не Ethernet. И даже не com. По-моему, эта вещичка устроена так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На средний провод подаётся постоянное напряжение, а кнопки замыкают соответствующие цепи, и тогда напряжение появляется на других линиях. Из интерфейсов, существующих в компьютере, здесь подойдёт только [LPT-порт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1284): центральный провод соединить с линией strobe и подать на него высокий уровень (логическую единицу). Другие линии соединить с любой из линий состояния и постоянно проверять на них логический уровень.

Проблема в том, что на современных компьютерах такого порта давно уже нет. Поэтому я могу посоветовать брать свой контроллер (например, STM32F103), с его помощью проверять состояние кнопок. Это легко делается через порты GPIO. На компьютер можно передавать данные с помощью USB, который встроен в этот контроллер. Но USB - штука довольно сложная, поэтому вам легче будет воспользоваться преобразователем USB-UART, например, CP2102.

Answer (score 1):

Это не COM порт чтобы напрямую с него считывать сигналы, этим занимается сетевая карта и обрабатывает по протоколу Ethernet.

Подключите этот пульт к COM-порту.

Comment: Уверены, что на фото это именно  ethernet c 8P8C (RJ45) разъемом, а не RJ45 для последовательного порта? (посмотрите внимательно на провода (в т.ч. в прозрачной части разъема))

Comment: @avp В вопросе сказано про Ethernet порт.

Comment: Может автор сам ошибается? Я как-то  с трудом представляю (технически возможно, но практического смысла не вижу) микроконтроллер встроенный прямо в кабель около пульта.

Comment: @avp Это контроллер может использовать последовательный порт, а автор спрашивает про Ethernet порт компа.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что я понятия не имею какой это кабель. Я вижу похожи на ethernet, пишу что это он. Главное, что я не понимаю как с ним работать. Возможно, я взялся за слишком сложный проект для своего уровня, но всё равно хотелось бы узнать что с ним делать. Опираясь на ваши комментарии, думаю что это COM кабель с разъёмом RJ-45. Думаю тогда сделать переходник с RJ-45 на COM разъём с одной стороны.

Comment: @aleko2104 Главное не кабель, а протокол передачи. Может напишите, что за контроллер?

Comment: @Alex78191 Не могу сказать что за контроллер (шёл в комплекте со столом), но он используется для регулировки высоты стола. Я думаю если уж это COM порт, то подключив через переходник (RJ45 - COM), получится ли получить какой либо сигнал, нажимая на кнопочки на пульте поочерёдно?

Comment: @aleko2104 получится.